Issues with Handling URL Schemes and App State Transitions in iOS App
I'm working on an iOS app that integrates with Spotify for authentication. I’m facing a problem where the app doesn’t handle URL schemes and app state transitions properly. Specifically, when Spotify redirects back to my app, it either doesn’t handle the URL correctly or doesn’t transition between states as expected. The authorization for spotify is successful, then my app reopens and nothing happens after that.
Expected Behavior:
When Spotify redirects to my app, it should correctly handle the URL and process authentication parameters.
Actual Behavior:
Even with URL handling code commented out, the app reopens from Spotify, which suggests a possible issue with how URL schemes or app state transitions are managed. The app’s state transitions don’t seem to be handled as expected.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified URL schemes and redirect URIs.
Implemented application(_:open:options:) for URL handling.
Tested various app states (foreground, background, suspended).

Relevant Code:
//This code should open my app using the URL from spotify but this code never triggers and yet my app opens anyways//
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("Received URL: \(url.absoluteString)")
    handleSpotifyURL(url)
    return true
}

private func handleSpotifyURL(_ url: URL) {
    // URL handling logic
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Logic for when the app becomes active
}


//Using latest software for xcode, testing on iphone 14 with up to date software and up to date spotify
As mentioned - have ensure that my info plist is configured correctly, that spotify authorizes correctly, that the redirect URI is correct in my code and on spotify for developers.
From the testing I've done I imagine there is something wrong with how my app gets opened vs how it should get opened with the callback URL triggering func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options:....
What I am expecting is that when spotify triggers the callback url - my app reopens with the above function and from there can retrieve the access token etc.
